# Node.js moving files between servers

Tags: node.js, git, file

As i see there is three ways of doing this.

- move file by file
- create zip file and move it
- use git

Git works like a charm, but how can i solve situation when i have one server connecting with multiple server and each folder should have it's own authentication path. An idea is to create linux user for each server which are connecting, and give access to anything is needed. That sound complex, perhaps there is easier way? For first two cases where we simply move files, is there any good module which do that?

Comment: Ansible is the best way of doing this type of work. You can create a custom module to send the files using git and then using ansible's other properties for the auth.

Comment: looks like an none free service, i am not looking for something like this.

Comment: Ansible is free buddy. Its open source.